# angular time picker not getting error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have used time picker for booking after booking i have stored in database.in edit booking i have passed time to time input field but i am getting error

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `01:00:00 pm` to be a date
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ngModel/datefmt?p0=01%3A00%3A00%20pm
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular.js:19807)
    at Object.ngModelWatch (angular.js:23289)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14235)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14506)
    at done (angular.js:9659)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9849)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:9790).i have enclosed my code
```

```js
.controller('EditCtrl', [
        '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$filter', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicLoading', '$timeout',
        function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {
  $http.get('**').success(function(data, dealers, response) {
   // $scope.booktime = data.Scheduled_Time;
    //console.log($scope.booktime);
    $scope.booktime="01:00:00 pm";
})
  
}
    ]);
```

```html
  <div ng-controller="EditCtrl">
    <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label" >Time</span>
            <input type="time" ng-model="booktime"  name="booktime" min="09:00:00" max="21:00:00"required="">
            </label>
            <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.booktime.$error">
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">* Mandatory</div>
              
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="max">Booking times: 9am - 9 pm</div>
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: convert it to date object, its not date

Answer (score 1):

you have to use in form of `$scope.booktime = new Date(dateString)`. ng-model for date/time input need to be valid date object, so you need to convert into valid date object

```
dt = new Date();
var time = dt.setHours(1) + ":" + dt.setMinutes(10) + ":" + dt.setSeconds(00);
var date= dt.getFullYear() + "/" + dt.getMonth() + "/" +dt.getDay() + " ";

$scope.booktime =new Date(date+ time;)
```

Comment: i have put $scope.booktime = new Date(data.Scheduled_Time); i am getting Invalid Date in console

Comment: data.Scheduled_Time what is the value?

Comment: 01:00:00 pm console i am getting

Comment: you should use complete date, not only time .right now you are passing time only like 09:00 AM which is not a date

Comment: i have put this $scope.booktime = new Date("1970, 0, 1, 14, 57, 0"); its not picking the value

Comment: use like new Date(1970, 0, 1, 14, 57, 0)

Comment: That I agree , they gave an example.similarly you must have new Date(your date) but in your case date in not known(what is day,month year) only time is know. So what date should be picked?

Comment: i want to pick only time in booking and i need to show time in edit booking how can i do?

Comment: @mojo you can split the value and pass it like val.split(":");

Comment: i am getting ncaught SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like below code, it will return you proper date.

```
  var date_yours= new Date(); 
  date_yours.setHours(1);
  date_yours.setMinutes(10);
 console.log(date_yours);
```

and for a formatted date (in your case you want time only). I have commented am/pm and using 24 hour format

```
function formatDate(date) {
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    /*  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12' */
      hours = hours < 10 ? '0'+hours : hours;
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes; 
      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes;
      //var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;


      return strTime ;

    }
```

Comment: <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label" >Time</span>
            <input type="time" ng-model="booktime"  name="booktime" min="09:00:00" max="21:00:00"required="">
            </label>
            <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.booktime.$error">
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">* Mandatory</div>
               >
            </div>
         </div>

Comment: <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label" >Time</span>
            <input type="time" ng-model="booktime"  name="booktime" min="09:00:00" max="21:00:00"required="">
            </label>
            <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.booktime.$error">
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">* Mandatory</div>
               >
            </div>
         </div>

Comment: no its not picking  $scope.booktime = new Date("14:57:00");

Comment: see and example http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/t3m6r/79/ , When are you getting error ? while displaying time on edit page ? or while updating the edit page (sending data to server) use the answer above to convert it to date while posting to server